How can I force the compiler to keep my parameters in the same registers when returning?
I'm trying to write some weird code that I'm planning on using for a very simple JIT. It's a bunch of small bytecode handler functions that I'll use in the generated executable that will look something like this:
// source code

#define HANDLER(name)                                                          \
    void name(WasmMemory *memory, WasmValue *stack, void **misc,               \
              uint64_t tmp1, uint64_t tmp2)
#define PARAMS memory, stack, misc, tmp1, tmp2
#define PRELUDE                                                                \
    start: asm volatile("" :: "r"(memory), "r"(stack), "r"(misc));
#define POSTLUDE                                                               \
    end:                                                                       \
    asm goto("" :: "r"(memory), "r"(stack), "r"(misc) ::start, end);           \
    return

HANDLER(memorysize) {
    PRELUDE;
    *stack++ = memory->size();
    POSTLUDE;
}

;; runtime generated code

call memorysize
call i32add
call i32mul
movabs rcx, 17 ;; rcx is tmp1 register, used in i32const
call i32const

The theory behind the current prelude/postlude is that if the compiler thinks we can jump to start right at the end of the function, it'll try to keep stuff in the same registers so it doesn't have to reset them before. This works well in smaller functions, but not in larger handlers (like for growing memory).
I've also tried a less platform-agnostic version:
#define HANDLER(name)                                                          \
    void name(WasmMemory *_memory, WasmValue *_stack, void **_misc,               \
              uint64_t tmp1, uint64_t tmp2)
#define PARAMS memory, stack, misc, tmp1, tmp2
#define PRELUDE                                                                \
    register auto memory asm("rdi") = _memory; \
    register auto stack asm("rsi") = _stack; \
    register auto misc asm("rdx") = _misc;
#define POSTLUDE                                                               \
    return

Which seems to work better, but the line

Passing parameters to or from routines written in assembler (or other languages) using non-standard calling conventions.
as a non-usecase in GCC's local register variable docs makes me think it might not work properly when I test on everything.

Is there any "proper" way of doing this? I've also considered something like adding a dummy function that I can properly tail call via [[clang::musttail]] return dummy(PARAMS); to at the end of every function, but the extra overhead there isn't ideal.

This is not C++. register is removed from C++ 8 years ago. auto in the shown context is removed from C++ 14 years ago.

Note well that inline assembly is a widely implemented C extension, and the details do vary among implementations.  Based on your tagging, I suppose you want answers for GCC and / or Clang.

Yeah, preferably I wouldn't have to have any inline assembly (i.e. the dummy function solution at the end) but really I'm fine with any solution that works with gcc and clang.
@3CxEZiVlQ is my usage of auto not the C++11 type alias version?

I thought it was a class storage specifier. Then you should pick one C or C++ that you actually use.

You may try volatile variable keyword, and inline function keyword

Are you trying to get GCC or Clang to compile functions for a custom calling convention where incoming arg registers are call-preserved?  I don't think GCC or Clang know how to do that.  GCC has some ABI-modifying options that tell it a register is call-clobbered or call-preserved, like GCC -fcall-used-rbx or -fcall-saved-r11.  Not sure if call-saved works on an arg-passing register like -fcall-saved-rdi.  Using it on a return-value reg is "disastrous" according to the man page, probably overwriting the return value.

Also, movabs rcx, 17 is very sub-optimal.  Your JIT should check values for (uint32_t)x == x and use mov ecx, imm32, else use mov rcx, constant and let the assembler pick movabs over mov only if the constant doesn't fit as i32.  You only need movabs with a symbol name where the assembler can't already see the "value" (address).  Or assemble with as -O2 and let it optimize mov rcx, 17 to mov ecx, 17.  (If using gcc instead of as directly, then -Wa,-O2; assembler optimization options are separate from compiler.)  I assume you're using GAS .intel_syntax noprefix.

Also, why are you calling functions for things as trivial as 32-bit integer add or multiply?  Have your JIT inline that with add or imul instructions.  call / ret are expensive compared to those.

@PeterCordes the goal here is to have as little platform-specific code as possible (maybe better to think of it as an unrolled interpreter rather than a JIT?). Right now that's really the sole objective - I plan to see how it performs vs. an actual interpreter that operates on the same bytecode. Also to answer your first question, that description sounds about right - only changes I want to persist are those to the stack parameter

I think the ABI flags sound like a good start though, thanks. Small note, no assembler at play here, just writing directly to executable memory, hence the very basic codegen

@3CxEZiVlQ: GNU C++ still supports register ... asm("symbol or register name").  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html  .  GCC and Clang still accept it with -std=c++23 (https://godbolt.org/z/a8h8E6Y8E I thought I might have to use __asm__ for c++23 unlike gnu++23, but no, probably because there isn't ambiguity with ISO C++ syntax.)  register ... asm() was never in ISO C++; GNU C++ decided to keep register as a keyword.  (GCC and Clang choke on int register = 123; even with -std=c++23, unfortunately.)

@csjh: You might be able to use some global register variables, and write functions that read/write those globals instead of having function args.  (Cast from uintptr_t to void* if some functions need a register to be an integer vs. some needing it to be a pointer.)    Like register uintptr_t RBX asm("rbx"); at global scope?  That forces everything using it to be 64-bit operand-size, though.  IDK if it works for registers that are normally arg-passing, like RDI.  If you use RDX and RCX, compiler-generated code might not be able to use idiv/div, or variable-count shifts without BMI2

Or your JIT logic could use call-preserved registers (RBX, RBP, R12-R15 in the x86-64 SysV ABI) for values it wants to survive calls.  That doesn't help if you want to pass the same value to multiple functions in a row, but if you have some important pointers that can live in fixed registers, that's a good use-case for a global register variable for that, and normal arg-passing for other things.
